# Data not getting submitted to DB after posting

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, sweetalert

When I press the submit button the Sweetalert pops up; when I press ok the page redirects me to my index page but the data is not posted in the DB.

This is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include ="TaskId,Title,Description,CreatedDate,Deadline,StatusId,ProjectId,Comment")] 
     OGP_PEG_.Models.Task task)
        {
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
           {
              db.Entry(task).State = EntityState.Modified;
              await db.SaveChangesAsync();
           }
           ViewBag.ProjectId = new SelectList(db.Projects, "IdProvisional", 
              "Title", task.ProjectId);
           ViewBag.StatusId = new SelectList(db.ProjectStatus, "StatusId", 
              "StatusType", task.StatusId);
           return View(task);
        }
```

And this is the JQuery code for submission:

```
$('#taskbtn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = $(this).closest("form");

    swal({
        title: "Gracias!",
        text: "Su comentario a sido grabado.",
        icon: "success",
        buttons: {
            cancel: true,
            confirm: "Submit",
            closeOnConfirm: false
        },

    }).then(function () {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (data != null) {
            swal({
                text: data,
                icon: "success"
            });
            data.submit();
            window.location.href = "/Tasks/Index";
        }

    });
});
```

My View:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Tasks"))
 {
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input id="taskbtn" type="submit" name="Comment" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
 }
```

Edit call:

```
   <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.TaskId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.TaskId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.TaskId })
   </td>
```

Comment: You do not have any code to call the `Edit` action method. Why do you expect the data to save ? Also your form does have only a submit button. What data you are expecting to be saved ?

Comment: @Shyju If I comment the code window.location the info save in the database but not redirect me after that.

Comment: because that is doing a normal form submit. So the next line won't be executed.

Comment: @Shyju How can I do to executed the first one(insert into the db) and the redirect me?

Comment: Your action method should return a Redirect response after saving. `return RedirectToAction("Index","Tasks");`

Comment: @Shyju Yeah I did! Thanks alot!!!